# Html and css multiple rows in table not working

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a table with multiple rows, but when I add a second one, only one link shows. I think this is an issue with my id in css, but am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#mydiv {
color: black;
height: 1000px;
width: 200px;
background-color: #828180;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 200px; /* 200px from top */
}   
</style>
<title>
Cathedral Project
</title>
</head>
<body type="text/css">
<h1>
<marquee behavior = "alternate" style = "background-color:#828180" scrolldelay = "1">
<a href="https://be43ada9-a-cc17453e-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/sau41.org/stephen-capraro/home/funny_3.jpg?attachauth=ANoY7cq6T-NPJuhfXWPCNobXQS33pGhZw8uo_BhUpozRiCu8JFK7_dWd6B-92bckzc8_3Vj9lQMh7jCL0mBVR-tYYg0LgIIx7yPZqbme0G-oKcRVfyd_GPuRrTtCuOT2wRhByl-QVpqrpa12yk5xqG9bluTqdQEyRgeMPCnz3mpcdjV9xKzoWOLUg2vCrGscyxdz84kFwm0hDZlH0I4LhEZZioG4kLd-fQ%3D%3D&attredirects=0" target="_blank"> <img src="gothic.jpg"> </a>
</marquee>
</h1>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="mydiv"><a href = "project.html">Home</a></td>
<tr>
<td id="mydiv"><a href = "stained_glass.html">Stained Glass</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh my lord...he has a marquee

Comment: You can only use an id once. Change mydiv to a class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to learn better coding skills.

The problem is your position attribute of `td`, and the solution is to remove `position:fixed;` from style tag. Better test it again.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing TR.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td id="mydiv"><a href="project.html">Home</a>
    </td>
</tr>   <<<<< You are missing a closing TR
<tr>
    <td id="mydiv"><a href="stained_glass.html">Stained Glass</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And here is improved CSS like the other poster mentioned (below):

```
#mydiv {
color: black;
height: 1000px;
width: 200px;
background-color: #828180;
left: 0;
top: 200px;
/* 200px from top */
}
```

Comment: Yes, But he need to remove fixed position yet !

Comment: Closing tr tags are optional in HTML, because the browser can always infer where they should go.